# How to set module breakpoint (bu) in WinDbg for operator new/operator delete?

Tags: windbg

Here is my problem:

```
0:001> x xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator*
00000000`06645e10 xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator delete (void *)
00000000`06645be0 xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator new (unsigned int)
0:001> bu "xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator delete"
0:001> bu "xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator new"
breakpoint 0 redefined
0:001> bu xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator delete
Couldn't resolve error at 'xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator delete'
0:001> bu xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator\ delete
Couldn't resolve error at 'xerces_depdom_2_8!xercesc_2_8::DOMStringHandle::operator\ delete'
```

First I try to quote the function name. No dice - trying to set a breakpoint on the `operator new` removes the one on `operator delete`. Meaning, the breakpoints are set incorrectly in the first place.

Unquoted tries do not work too.

So, how do I do it?

**EDIT**

There is a reason I want to use bu, rather than bp. The breakpoints are set in a script. Using actual addresses for breakpoints is not a good idea, because they might change from run to run, unlike the function names. Besides, bu allows to set the breakpoint before the respective module is loaded, again unlike bp.

So, let me clarify the question - breakpoints are set before the respective modules are loaded.

Comment: [Breakpoint Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538936(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use braces if there are spaces in the symbol name you want to use:

```
bu (blah!operator new)
```

See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in particular the section on *Breakpoints Using Complicated Text*

Comment: This is great, thanks! I would resort to bm <prefix>* and then eyeball the symbol name and then use bu on the corresponding address. But this is way better, thanks again :)

Comment: @MarcSherman yes there are lots of different ways of setting breakpoints including using source file line number and the very complicated masm and c++ syntax, there is always a way of finding and setting breakpoints for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `bu @!"blah!operator new"`, which has the advantage of referring `'<'`, `'>'` characters which are used a lot in the template method. This is also mentioned in the link of EdChum's answer.